# Java package porting

Tags: java, package, httpsurlconnection

I am new to Java and I need to use HttpsUrlConnection from javax.net.ssl on some embedded platform (jme, clds 1.0).
Is it possible that I get a jar (from the Internet) that has this class with all the dependencies?

Update:
I am using JDK 1.1.8

Comment: please specify which version of java

Comment: @MarcT I am not sure whether my answer is correct but I am using JDK 1.1.8

Comment: The HttpsUrlConnection is normally located into rt.jar (Java SE)... if not, you have to check which compact profile you use. refer to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-profiles-2227131.html as a starting point as I don't know how to add 'removed' functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

The HttpsUrlConnection is normally located into rt.jar (Java SE) into package javax.net.ssl This package is present in Compact profile 1 (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/compactprofiles/compactprofiles.html